# Drawing on canvas within iframe not going full screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, oculus

### Description

Hello, I created a sketchfab account and uploaded a 3D skull. Sketchfab has created a way to view this 3D model with the Oculus rift by just adding `/embed?oculus=2` ( *for the dk2 version which I have* )

*( before you continue reading please read this: when I say for the oculus rift.. all it does is create two images of this 3D skull side by side and put it in full screen. **That is it**. There is no configuration required for this to work with the oculus rift ( other than the standard setup.. which I already did))*

Everything seems to be working except when I put it in full screen. This is 
the outcome:

[image: cranium sketchfab oculus rift]

Notice that the canvas goes full screen, but not the drawing of the 3D model split into two parts. For some reason it stays in the far left corner.

### Embed Code

```
<iframe width="640" height="480" src="https://sketchfab.com/models/a0ea79b025d548ab98787bf4bdf45f74/embed?oculus=2" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" onmousewheel=""></iframe>

    <p style="font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; margin: 5px; color: #4A4A4A;">
        <a href="https://sketchfab.com/models/a0ea79b025d548ab98787bf4bdf45f74?utm_source=oembed&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=a0ea79b025d548ab98787bf4bdf45f74" target="_blank" style="font-weight: bold; color: #1CAAD9;">Cranium</a>
        by <a href="https://sketchfab.com/grimbode?utm_source=oembed&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=a0ea79b025d548ab98787bf4bdf45f74" target="_blank" style="font-weight: bold; color: #1CAAD9;">grimbode</a>
        on <a href="https://sketchfab.com?utm_source=oembed&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=a0ea79b025d548ab98787bf4bdf45f74" target="_blank" style="font-weight: bold; color: #1CAAD9;">Sketchfab</a>
    </p>
```

### What I have tried

I am using a mac and I've tried this in `chrome, safari, firefox` with the exact same result.

I have tried changing the `iframe` dimensions with little success.

I have changed it to `dk1` to see if there was a difference, there wasn't.

### Question

Why doesn't the skull drawing on the `canvas` within the `iframe` go full screen ? How can I get the drawing of this skull on the canvas to go full screen ?

A full and complete answer would be cool, however an indication of what I would need to do would suffice. Thank you.

### EDIT: Something worth noting

If I use the original embed ( meaning `/embed` instead of `/embed?oculus=2` ) and put it in full screen it works with no problems.

[image]

Comment: the oculus one probably has the resolution hard-coded? a guess

Comment: canvas usually has specific widths and height set for it, do you have the css / html for the canvas?  Also I'm not sure but I think if you change the size of the canvas, you may need to redraw everything in the canvas

Comment: you might be able to `iframe{zoom:2}` or something...

Comment: i mean the version they made for oculus probably has the rift's screen rez hard-coded. that would make sense since aspect ratios would need to be tightly managed to prevent headaches and to use all the screen real-estate; you can't do good 3D with a couple of 2.35:1 rectangles, and ideally you have a pair of squares.

Comment: [This may help](http://community.createjs.com/discussions/createjs/547-resizing-canvas-and-its-content-proportionally-cross-platform) - it looks like when you resize your window, you need to use js to resize your canvas and then either redraw or scale it's contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a discussion with one of the staff members at [sketchfab](https://sketchfab.com/)

[Discussion on sketchfab here](http://forum.sketchfab.com/t/oculus-rift-mode-isnt-working-correctly/1478)

### Solution to my original problem:

> You are trying to use the hard coded version of the oculus and we
>   probably won't support/improve it. It was very experimental at that
>   time. The good way to test VR is to get a browser with VR support.

So this means to use one of the experimental webvr browers and to not modify the sketchfab model url.

### Additional problems and known issues:

There were some further issues with using the webvr browers and the embed code.

---

With FirefoxNightly ensure Oculus Rift is plugged in before starting the 3D model, otherwise it may not work properly.

> Indeed I tested nightly and I had the same error (but only when I
>   didn't have any oculus plugged in). This error should be fixed on the
>   next release.

---

Chrome for me is crashing but seems to be working for other people. I am using Mac. I do not know if this is causing a problem or not. One thing is for sure, webvr browers are still unstable.

---

### Conclusion

> Anway, we'll probably put more effort on VR support once the webvr
>   browsers are more stable, but still early feedback are welcomed.